# How to do a count by month/year for a user that connected on any platform?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table called users that holds users ids, as well as a few tables like `cloud_storage_a`, `cloud_storage_b` and `cloud_storage_c`. If a user exists in cloud_storage_a, that means they are a connected to cloud storage a. A user can exist in many cloud storages too. Here's an example:

```
id      | address      | name      | created_at
--------------------------------------------------
123     | 23 Oak Ave   | Melissa   | 2014-05-12
333     | 18 Robson Rd | Steve     | 2015-01-20
421     | 95 Ottawa St | Helen     | 2015-02-10
555     | 12 Highland  | Amit      | 2015-05-17
192     | 39 Anchor Rd | Oliver    | 2015-08-25
```

`cloud_storage_a`

```
user_id | created_at
---------------------
 421    | 2015-03-05
 333    | 2015-02-01
```

`cloud_storage_b`

```
user_id | created_at
----------------------
 555    | 2015-07-20
```

`cloud_storage_c`

```
user_id | created_at
---------------------
 192    | 2015-08-26
 555    | 2015-08-01
```

In this example, the user 555 signed up in 05-2015 but didn't add cloud storage b until 07-2015, and joined cloud storage c 08-2015. I currently have a query to determine the average number of days it takes for users to connect to each cloud storage grouped by month/year:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t1."Month",'-',t1."Year") as "Month-Year", a_connection_date::int AS "Average Days to Connect to A", 
b_connection_date::int as "Average Days to Connect to B", c_connection_date::int as "Average Days to Connect to C"
from ( 
  SELECT extract(YEAR from u.created_at) as "Year", extract(MONTH from u.created_at) as "Month", 
  AVG(extract (day from c.created_at - u.created_at)) as a_connection_date
  FROM users u INNER JOIN cloud_storage_a c ON u.id=c.user_id
  GROUP BY 1, EXTRACT(MONTH from u.created_at), EXTRACT(YEAR from u.created_at)
  order by "Year","Month") as t1
full join (SELECT extract(YEAR from u.created_at) as "Year", 
  extract(MONTH from u.created_at) as "Month", AVG(extract (day from 
  c.created_at - u.created_at)) as b_connection_date
  FROM users u INNER JOIN cloud_storage_b c ON u.id=c.user_id
  GROUP BY 1, EXTRACT(MONTH from u.created_at), EXTRACT(YEAR from u.created_at)
  order by "Year","Month"
) as t2
  on concat(t1."Year",'-',t1."Month")=concat(t2."Year",'-',t2."Month")
  full join (SELECT extract(YEAR from u.created_at) as "Year",     
  extract(MONTH from u.created_at) as "Month", AVG(extract (day from      
  c.created_at - u.created_at)) as c_connection_date
  FROM users u INNER JOIN cloud_storage_c c ON u.id=c.user_id
  GROUP BY 1, EXTRACT(MONTH from u.created_at), EXTRACT(YEAR from   u.created_at)
  order by "Year","Month"
) as t3
on concat(t1."Year",'-',t1."Month")=concat(t3."Year",'-',t3."Month")
ORDER BY t1."Year",t1."Month";
```

Which returns something like:

```
Month-Year | Average Days to Connect to A | Average Days to Connect to B | Average Days to Connect to C 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1-2015     | 11                           |                              |
2-2015     | 23                           |                              |                              
5-2015     |                              | 63                           | 73
8-2015     |                              |                              | 1
```

I want to also have a column for the "Average Days to Connect to ANY Cloud" (ie for user 555, they connected to cloud b before cloud c so the average number of days for 5-2015 would be 63 days instead of 73. Mind you, this example is a small subset so there could be many users that sign up in 5-2015 and connect to various clouds!

Answer (score 1):

Create a view to hold all cloud storages:

```
create view all_cloud_storages as
select user_id, created_at from cloud_storage_a union
select user_id, created_at from cloud_storage_b union
select user_id, created_at from cloud_storage_c union
....
select user_id, created_at from cloud_storage_z;
```

Then change the "select" you wrote to retrieve records from the new "view":

```
SELECT CONCAT(t1."Month",'-',t1."Year") as "Month-Year", 
       connection_date::int AS "Average Days to Connect to Any",
       first_connection_date as "Date of First Connection in Month",
       last_connection_date as "Date of Last Connection in Month"
FROM   ( 
         SELECT  extract(YEAR from u.created_at) as "Year", 
                 extract(MONTH from u.created_at) as "Month", 
                 AVG(extract (day from c.created_at - u.created_at)) 
                    as connection_date,
                 MIN(c.created_at) AS first_connection_date,
                 MAX(c.created_at) AS last_connection_date
           FROM  users u 
           INNER JOIN all_cloud_storages c ON u.id=c.user_id
           GROUP BY 1, 
                    EXTRACT(MONTH from u.created_at), 
                    EXTRACT(YEAR from u.created_at)
           order by "Year","Month"
       ) as t1
 ORDER BY t1."Year",t1."Month";
```

Comment: Does this also grab the first date in which a user connected to any cloud?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your updated query as I simply want to find the average of the difference in dates between the day the user signed up u.created_at and the day the user joined their first cloud min(c.created_at) - why is there the max?

Comment: @AshleyI.:  I supposed you could want that info as well. You can just remove it from the query if you wish.

Comment: Thanks christian. Does the AVG(extract (day from c.created_at - u.created_at)) as connection_date use the minimum c.created_at date though?